# duplicate result in group_concat

Tags: mysql

I have this data in my database(3,15,6,4,15), and I tried to show it on my table using group concat, the problem is i got duplicate results. (3,15,6,4,15,3,15,6,4,15,3,15,6,4,15).

I tried to use distinct but it eliminate also the other "15".

What is the best solution for that?
thanks!

this is my query

```
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(written.score separator ' - ') as Wscore, student_subject.*,SUM(written.score) as total, SUM(written.item) as item FROM users JOIN written ON users.idnumber=written.idnumber JOIN student_subject ON users.idnumber=student_subject.idnumber WHERE student_subject.teacher='$login_session' AND written.section='$section' AND written.level='$level' AND written.year='$year' AND written.subject='$subject' AND users.gender='male' AND written.period='first' GROUP BY users.idnumber order by users.lname
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want `distinct` in the `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct w.score separator ' - ') as Wscore, 
       ss.*, SUM(w.score) as total, SUM(w.item) as item
FROM users u JOIN
     written w
     ON u.idnumber = w.idnumber JOIN
     student_subject ss
     ON u.idnumber = ss.idnumber
WHERE ss.teacher = '$login_session' AND w.section='$section' AND 
      w.level = '$level' AND w.year = '$year' AND w.subject = '$subject' AND 
      u.gender = 'male' AND w.period = 'first' 
GROUP BY u.idnumber
order by u.lname;
```

Notice how table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: actually I tried to use the distinct inside the group concat but the other 15 is not shown

Comment: @misdirection . . . If you want to eliminate duplicates, why do you want 15 to appear twice?

Comment: because it is in my database (3,15,6,4,15)